# \luaexec inside \num causes errors

Tags: luatex, siunitx, luacode

To me, an attractive feature in LuaTeX is the ability to effectively perform calculations directly in the document. Now say I want a command `\proc` that performs calculations and then formats the numbers using `\num` from `siunitx`. I tried the code below, which causes a painful death filled with obscure error messages. Substituting `\luaexec` with `\directlua` works, but I have the impression that it is better to stay away from that primitive command if possible. I tried messing around with `\expandafter`s without any luck. How can I solve this?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{luacode,siunitx}

\newcommand\proc[1]{%
    \num{%
        \luaexec{tex.sprint(#1)}%
    }%
}


\begin{document}

\proc{2+3}

\end{document}
```

Comment: `\luaexec` is not fully expandable. It can't work.

Comment: @egreg So it is completely impossible?

Comment: @Gaussler Completely impossible depending on what you want. The main benefit of `\luaexec` is that it enables certain characters like ``\\``, `\%`, etc. If you are not using those, why use `\luaexec` in that particular case?

Comment: You should do it in two steps: define with the `newtoken` library a macro that then you pass to `\num`. Maybe there are cleverer ways: the more I look into the LuaTeX manual, the less I understand.

Comment: I am currently experimenting with getting `tex.sprint` to print `"\num{"..<theresult>.."}"`, where `..` denotes joined strings (I think). This should work, but I am not yet very familiar with how to get backslashes and brackets into `luaexec`, so it takes some time.

Comment: If you want to put Lua code there, just use `\directlua` like @egreg (almost) says

Comment: There can be quirks with escaping backslashes or `%`, but `\directlua` is surely the way to go, if you haven't those.

Comment: Another possible solution: Is there a function like `tex.getcommand("num")(<argument to put into \num>)` that allows us to run TeX commands in Lua? There is one for ConTeXt commands, but I haven't found one for LuaLaTeX commands yet.

Answer (score 3):

You need an expandable command here. the LuaTeX `\directlua` gives expandable access to lua so:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{siunitx}

\newcommand\proc[1]{%
    \num{%
        \directlua{tex.sprint(#1)}%
    }%
}


\begin{document}

\proc{2+3}

\end{document}
```